# How to add a log out button in my Pentaho CDE dashboard?

Tags: button, logging, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to add a log out button to my Pentaho CDE dashboard that redirects me to the login page and kills the logged-in user's session.

How can I do that?

Comment: Logout option comes by default when you login into bi sever, why you want extra button?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a CDE button to your dashboard that redirect the page to:

http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Logout - Remember to replace localhost with your hostname or IP address